# I'm having trouble with my php code to mysql database . Database cannot be read

Tags: php, mysql

I've been writing a php code for my project but I'm having trouble reading data from my xampp database. Every time I put my username & password in the the required fields, an error comes up. I want the code to display the next form after I put in the username  and the password. The database I'm using is called sales and has a table which has the fields, id, username and password. I'm new to php and if anyone out there can help me correct the  code, I'll really appreciate it.

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',"");
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysqli_error());
 }

  //Select database
   $db = mysqli_select_db( $link,'sales');
   if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }

  //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
  function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($str);
  }

  //Sanitize the POST values
  $login = clean($_POST['username']);
  $password = clean($_POST['password']);

  //Input Validations
  if($login == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
    $errflag = true;
  }
  if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
  }

 //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
  if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
  }

  //Create query
  $qry="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password'";
  $result=mysqli_query($qry);

  //Check whether the query was successful or not
  if($result) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['name'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['position'];
        //$_SESSION['SESS_PRO_PIC'] = $member['profImage'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: main/index.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
  }else {
    die("Query failed");
  }
  ?>
```

Afterwards,it should redirect to this form (index.php) which is located on a different  folder.
You an download the file here
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vIuKOtG0v9eZmKEnJQk3LR3-0p6wqtnd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What error do you get?...

Comment: Username missing and Password missing

Comment: Can you maybe give the full error message?

Comment: If it's missing, can you include the code for the `<form>` it's being submitted from.

Comment: Hi, this is the error (https://ibb.co/Smschcm)

Comment: ok, i'll upload the form

Comment: Can you improve the question's title and content so that it would be relevant to others too? For example, you could improve the title by including a hint regarding what the issue is, and you can be more specific regarding where you think the error is in the code you have provided?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements. Also the clean function is very likely damaging your data and you should get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

try checking if the form submit button has been set using `isset()` function before validating user input

Comment: I used isset before I posted the question.